# Which pins to mod on Intel Celeron E3300?

Tags: cpu, overclocking

I have an Intel Celeron E3300 Core Duo processor at 2.50 GHz with an 800 FSB. I aim to increase its speed to 3.33 GHz and the FSB to 1066. My motherboard, an ECS G31t-M7, supports this modification. Attached is a photo of the actual CPU:
[image]

Comment: What makes you think this is even possible?

Comment: If you look at the picture, you'll notice that there are no pins.

Comment: http://download.intel.com/design/processor/datashts/318732.pdf

Comment: The pins are on the motherboard. These are the golden dots that connect to the pins.

Answer (score 2):

Success! Went for the same two lands as in the picture above, which increased the bus speed from 200 to 266 MHz and the Rated FSB from 800 to 1066 MHz. CPU operates at 3333 MHz now. If you have a similar CPU architecture and seek enhanced performance, I recommend this modification. It's cost-effective and worthwhile. Post-modification, my CPU's temperature remains within the safe range. Here's the final result:"

[image]
[image]
[image: Here's the end result]

Comment: What's the second image?

Comment: It's a snapshot of RealTemp. It shows that temperature is well within the safe range and that the processor is running at 3333 Mhz/core.